# How to make dropdownlist in accordion using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create accordion that has a dropdownlist, but the problem is on my dropdownlist is not showing any list for selection and need some help around it. Below is my logic that have attempted to do and was not successful.

```
 <!-- Card body -->
                <div class="accordion md-accordion" id="accordionEx" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                    <!-- Accordion card -->
                    <div class="card">

                        <!-- Card header -->
                        <div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne1">
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordionEx" href="#collapseOne1" aria-expanded="true"
                               aria-controls="collapseOne1">
                                <h5 class="mb-0">
                                    This is a Sample Module <i class="fas fa-angle-down rotate-icon"></i>
                                </h5>
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Card body -->
                        <div id="collapseOne1" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne1"
                             data-parent="#accordionEx">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="dropdown">

                                    <!--Trigger-->

                                    <a type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></a>


                                    <!--Menu-->
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="media"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Media</a>
                                        
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for disregarding your code, but I merged Collapse and Dropdown code from Bootstrap website and it's working and I think this is what you wanted to achieve.

You probably have messed up bootstrap classes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test</title>
  <style>

  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>

  <div id="accordion">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true"
            aria-controls="collapseOne">
            Collapsible Group Item #1
          </button>
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="dropdown show">
            <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink"
              data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown link
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-controls="collapseTwo">
            Collapsible Group Item #2
          </button>
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          Content 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
            Collapsible Group Item #3
          </button>
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          Content 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```